# Json string sending From IOS to PHP server?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

When i am trying to send **JSON** string to server the result seems to be like this

> "["sudheer@gmail.com","venkat@gmail.com"]"

How to remove start and end double quotes response.

What mistake am I doing and why is it coming of like this?

I want output like

> ["sudheer@gmail.com","venkat@gmail.com"]

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl........."];
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = @[@"sudheer@gmail.com", @"venkat@gmail.com"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *json;
NSString *jsonString;

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:arrayOfStrings])
{
    // Serialize the dictionary
    json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayOfStrings options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    // If no errors, let's view the JSON
    if (json != nil && error == nil)
    {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);

        //NSString *cleanedString=[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"" withString:@""];

    }
}


NSString *userId = [delegate.objectId stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *projectId = [@"gcyn7uyUVh" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString* requestURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithString:requestURL]]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
//NSString *emails = [addSponsorEmailStringInModel componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&projectSponsor=%@&projectid=%@", userId,jsonString,projectId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
_addSponsorserverRplyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"add sponsor Response Is :%@",_addSponsorserverRplyString);
```

Comment: Are you getting the above format `"["sudheer@gmail.com", "venkat@gmail.com"]"` in PHP?

Comment: I've run you code and the output I get is `["sudheer@gmail.com","venkat@gmail.com"]` so no double quotes. Your issue lies els where

Comment: Hey NSLog generally may or may not add double quotes. It totally depends on the type of object. So dont believe it much. Just try to take this into an array and check what happens

Comment: nslog showing like["sudheer@gmail.com","venkat@gmail.com"]  but backend "["sudheer@gmail.com","venkat@gmail.com"] " its showing like